# The best way to load external js files at the top level

Tags: javascript, frontend, webclient, single-page-application

The scenario is I create a web site through visual studio, there're more than one spa in my web site, each spa at one folder. The structure look like this:

- WebApps

  - common foler
  - libraries folder
  - SPA1 folder

    - views folder
    - scripts folder
    - styles folder
    - index.html
  - SPA2

    - views folder
    - scripts folder
    - styles folder
    - index.html

Each of the index.html need to references external js and css files. Lots of the files are same, such as jQuery. Is there a way to reference common external files at WebApps level, instead of reference too much same libraries in each SPA?

Comment: are you trying to compile into one final file?

Comment: @brianxautumn do you mean compile every SPAs' external files into one file? I only want to compile the same external files into one file and share it with different SPAs.